# Track Vimeo via Google Tag Manager without iframes

Tags: vimeo, google-tag-manager

I'm helping out with a university page, and they use Adobe CQ5 as their cms. Anyway, I'm trying to track Vimeo vids via Google Tag Manager without inputting codes into the iframe as we are only allowed to embed media via CQ5 components (we're restricted to using the components because IT set the software to accommodate authors of varying skill levels). I've found an ideal tutorial for YouTube, where all coding is done via GTM and wonder if there's a similar one for Vimeo: http://www.optimizesmart.com/youtube-video-tracking-via-google-tag-manager/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you can ensure that jQuery is loaded and you have to ability to add a custom plugin to your page code.

Check out [vimeo.ga.js](http://www.sanderheilbron.nl/vimeo.ga.js/) for details. You won't be able to get extended events like progress tracking unless you can modify the embed code, but you'll get play, pause, resume, and completed.

Comment: Judging from the code, I'd have to apply it for every single video on a page, yes? It won't just pick up all the videos on the page? Thanks again.

Comment: No, it will work with all videos on the page. Just include jQuery and the vimeo.ga.js once on the page.

Comment: Well, I've tried (https://github.com/sanderheilbron/vimeo.ga.js/issues/14) implementing it, but since the implementation, all that happens is a giant chunk of 'undefined' shows up in my results...not sure what's wrong there...